# How to alter OS X screen pixel values in real time?

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

Is there any way, using Accessibility APIs or otherwise, for my Cocoa application to change pixel values of hardware screen in realtime while allowing user to work with other applications as usual?

Or, trying to put it in another words, I want to draw directly over system screen (not application-specific canvas) without affecting system behavior.

Existing examples of such low-level manipulations:

- Native OS X grayscale and inverted color accessibility modes.
- An app called [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com), which changes screen colors to match artificial lighting after sunset (existence of f.lux means there’s got to be some sort of suitable public API).

I’m not an experienced OS X programmer, so this might actually be stupidly simple.

Comment: You would not be using the accessibility API. You would have to look for other APIs such as the display API or graphics API

Comment: @unobf: Thanks for the pointers! Googling that up now. (I thought it’s related to Accessibility because f.lux, for example, requires—or used to require, if I recall correctly—that you add it under Security & Privacy > Accessibility page of System Preferences.)

Comment: Do you want to alter pixels in 1) your own app's windows? 2) other (all) app's windows? 3) the desktop (behind all windows & onscreen icons)? or 4) all the above?

Comment: As far as f.lux goes… I'd just adjust the monitor brightness (perhaps based on room brightness as measured by iSight?).

Comment: And as far as the research that f.lux was based on goes… it didn't test the effects of reading white text on a black screen.

Comment: @geowar, the app has to manipulate all screen pixel values, not specific to desktop or its own or any other app’s windows. f.lux was mentioned as existing implementation of this functionality, specifics related to their research are of no interest to me.

Comment: So far searching by display APIs led me to [Quartz Display Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/index.html), which seems to be promising.

Comment: @Tony did you have any luck building this? I'm trying to figure out the exact same problem now.

Comment: @StephenTetreault I recall I was onto something but I have no sample to share. I took a break from it a while ago. The Quartz reference linked above (e.g. CGSetDisplayTransferByTable) is promising.

Comment: @StephenTetreault If you reached any success, I’m all ears too ;)